# how to delete a comma separated value in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field in my database table called image and i am storing the image in this field like (1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg,4.jpg). So I have to delete the second image in table column which is 2.jpg.

Comment: String values as csv is **very bad** database design

Comment: Hint, if you want to take second value of that string use `explode` and take `$result[1];`. For here on is on your own :)

Comment: If i were you, i will create a new table `other_images` and join it with existing image table.

Comment: how do i do that can you brief me something.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## Note:

- That is not the proper way to store file names or data alike in a column field in your table.
- You should fix your post and include the code you are working on.

You should have stored it in your `image` column like this:

```
| image |
| 1.jpg |
| 2.jpg |
| 3.jpg |
| 4.jpg |
```

Not like this:

```
| image                   |
| 1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg,4.jpg |
```

## Answer:

But if you are stuck with that and really just want to remove the `2.jpg` from the given string, you can use `explode()` function of PHP. Check it [here](http://php.net/explode). (Please don't be intimidated by this code. I just put some comments inside to explain the functions of each line):

All you have to do with this code is to replace the right `table` name, `column` name and `variable` (if necessary).

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){

  $userDelete = $_REQUEST['val'];
  $newString = "";
  $rs = mysqli_query($YourDBConnection,"SELECT id, data FROM arr");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)){
      $id = $row["id"];
      $data = $row["data"];
      $exploded = explode(",",$data);
      $counter = count($exploded);
        for($x = 0; $x<$counter; $x++){ /* THIS LOOP WILL REMOVE THE REQUESTED DATA TO REMOVE */

          if($userDelete != $exploded[$x]){

            $newString = $newString.",".$exploded[$x];

          } /* END OF IF THE REQUESTED TO DELETE IS NOT THE SAME WITH EXPLODED DATA */

        } /* END OF FOR LOOP */

    mysqli_query($YourDBConnection,"UPDATE arr SET data = '$newString' WHERE id='$id'");

    } /* END OF WHILE LOOP */

} /* END OF ISSET REQUEST ID */
```

## Recommendation:

If you properly inserted it in your column field, you can just use `DELETE query` to remove the `2.jpg` from your database:

```
DELETE FROM yourTableName WHERE image = '2.jpg'
```

But it will permanently remove the data from your database. I recommend to add another column that will state the action of that picture, if it will be hidden or will be shown to the front end.

Example, we have a column named `action`, and it will only have the value of `1` or `0`. `1` triggers to show the image, `0` for hiding the image.

Comment: I have tried this bit of code but its not working in many sense.

Comment: No sir it's a image gallery where i am uploading multiple image and storing it into the db table in comma seprated values .So my question is when i click on the delete button of that particular image such as 2.jpg then it should be delete from the database table in comma seprated string

Comment: if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){   
 $userDelete = $_REQUEST['val'];
 $sql ="SELECT * FROM arr ";
 $rs = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 $data=mysql_fetch_row($rs); 
 $userArray=explode(",",$data[1]);
 $deleteKey = array_search($userDelete,$userArray);
 if($deleteKey !== FALSE) {
  
  $del_sql ="DELETE FROM arr WHERE column = '".$deleteKey."'";
  echo $del_sql;
  $del_rs = mysql_query($del_sql) or die(mysql_error());
  if($del_rs){
  echo "Record Deleted Successfully";
  }
 }  
 }

Comment: @user3565243 - did you get the point of the "SAMPLE" code I have given? Of course you have to tweak it based on your real data, and not just to copy+paste+run it. And please put that code in your post. And not putting it all in the comment section

Comment: Thanks for your support sir but it still giving me the  Undefined offset: 5 where $exploded[$x] is used i am not getting why this happens.Please check this out thanks Raghvendra

Comment: @user3565243 - you just have to remove the `=` in the for loop. Updated my answer, I just removed the `=`

Comment: Ok Logan when i try to echo the update statement it give me this output UPDATE arr SET column = ',,,,,' WHERE id='1' . Why these commas are there . there should be a exploded value of given string that i have clicked as a link to delete the image. The column is the field name where i am stroring the image.

Comment: if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
  $userDelete = $_REQUEST['val'];
  $newString = "";
  $rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM arr");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
      $id = $row["id"];
      $data1 = $row["column"];
      $exploded = explode(",",$data1);
      $counter = count($exploded);
  for($x = 0; $x < $counter; $x++){ 
          if($userDelete != $counter[$x]){
            $newString = $newString.",".$counter[$x];
   print_r($newString);
          } 
        } 
  $SQL="UPDATE arr SET column = '$newString' WHERE id='$id'";
    mysql_query($SQL);
    } 
}

Comment: @user3565243 - You are **WRONG** with assigning to `$newString` variable. It should be `$newString = $newString.",".$exploded[$x];` **NOT** `$newString = $newString.",".$counter[$x];` **AND** `if($userDelete != $exploded[$x]){` **NOT** `if($userDelete != $counter[$x]){`

Comment: yes the code is right but while running the update query the sql gives me an error . I think the update query is not right. Can u please check that out . Thanks

Comment: @user3565243 - change the necessary table name, column name and your variable for your connection in your update query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select image column from the database table, and then you need to write the following script:

```
$oldimages = '1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg,4.jpg';
$replaceImage = '2.jpg';
$newImages = str_replace($replaceImage.",", "", $oldimages);
// then write update query.
mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE images SET images = '$newImages' WHERE id=$pid");
```